# ¿Cómo quitar el formato por defecto añadido al carácter Unicode  para que tenga el comportamiento normal, como en ?

Tags: java, unicode

Tengo el siguiente código de Java:

```
 final String[] DAYS_OF_WEEK = {
            " \033[37m\u2649· \uD83C\uDD70 Atenea ", // Aries         Atenea 
            " \033[32m\u2649· \uD83C\uDD71 Brigid ", // Tauro         Brigid 
            " \033[36m\u264A· \uD83C\uDD72 Ceres  ", // Geminis       Ceres  
            " \033[34m\u264B· \uD83C\uDD73 Diana  ", // Cáncer        Diana  
            " \033[35m\u264C· \uD83C\uDD74 Epona  ", // Leo           Epona  
            " \033[31m\u264D· \uD83C\uDD75 Freya  ", // Virgo         Freya  
            " \033[33m\u264E· \uD83C\uDD76 Gaia   ", // Libra         Gaia   
            " \033[31m\u264F· \uD83C\uDD77 Hathor ", // Escorpio      Hathor 
            " \033[35m\u26CE· \uD83C\uDD78 Inanna ", // Ofiuco        Inanna 
             "\033[34m\u2650· \uD83C\uDD79 Juno   ", // Sagitario     Juno   
             "\033[36m\u2651· \uD83C\uDD7A Kore   ", // Capricornio   Kore   
             "\033[32m\u2652· \uD83C\uDD7B Lilith ", // Acuario       Lilith 
             "\033[37m\u2653· \uD83C\uDD7C Maria  ", // Piscis        Maria  
        };
```

He intentado de todo, ¡Hasta consultar a YouChat! y no obtengo una solución.
Anexo una imagen de lo obtenido [image: (en consola PowerShell Vs Code Windows)]

Como se puede observar, los personajes (caracteres) A y B adquieren un formato de Emoji, que me impide formatear la salida del texto.

¿Alguien conoce una solución sencilla?

He leído que los caracteres Unicode tienen la posibilidad de tener presentación solo texto, pero no me aclaro como se puede hacer.

YouChat, me sugiere librerías (alguna incluso Deprecada), y no estoy por la labor de añadir cosas que no entiendo.

Comment: Hola Manuel, me llama la atención que en **A** y en **B**, es igual **\033[37m\u2649**, cuando todos los demás parecen ir en escalera, será la raiz de tu problema?

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo, no es que adquieran formato de emoji, es que derechamente lo son, entonces no puedes formatear como a un texto lo que básicamente es una imagen. Yo iría por lo fácil y buscaría otra familia de unicode donde estuvieran todas las letras. Por ejemplo https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/enclosed-alphanumeric-supplement/ las que tienen un circulo negro están todas las letras

Comment: @Yussef ¡Gracias! pero me proporciona  que no es lo que se busca, aunque su comportamiento es el esperado, pero el tamaño del glifo es mucho menor. Por otro lado, esperaba que la solución me permitiese aprender a modificar este tipo de caracteres.

Comment: Lo otro es busques una fuente algo como esto https://www.dafont.com/es/stencilie.font

Comment: @Yussef Es interesante pero el objetivo es no cambiar demasiadas cosas, por ejemplo, las fuentes por defecto. Por eso, es la idea de usar Unicode.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y a mí me funciona. A excepción de los emojis de los signos del zodiaco. El problema es irreproducible.

Comment: @Mateo estas diciendo que a ti la letra `A` te aparece con color Gris y la `B` de color verde?

Comment: @Yussef exacto. Aclaro que solo funciona en Linux. Para Windows necesitas usar llamadas a la API del sistema o una librería que lo haga por vos.

Comment: Es posible que el problema sea de la tipografía del terminal.

Comment: @Mateo ¿en la página de [Unicode "P"](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F17F/) Te aparecen todos los glifos "White on black squared Latin letters" sobre fondo negro? A mí me aparecen la "A", "B", "O" y "P" con formato de color.  Uso Edge.

Comment: @MarcePuente ¡Perdón por la tardanza! Pero tuve que investigar a que te referías. El Unicode \u26CE es el nuevo glifo para el "treceavo signo del zodiaco" (cosas de la Nasa), y como es nuevo no se encuentra junto a los demás. . Y sí, tenía duplicado a tauro que es \u2648

Comment: @Manuel no me quedo clara la pregunta. Pero bueno, a lo que voy es que a mí se me muestra bien el color de todos.